# POST and PUT via Socket.IO in Java

Tags: java, android, socket.io, sails.js

I am developing an Android client with [nkzawa's Socket.IO-client.java](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java), and can't figure out how to make a POST- or PUT request with data in the request body via a socket.

I have managed to perform a GET request, which is done like this:

```
...
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("url", "/list/subscribe/");
socket.emit("get", obj);
...
```

I have tried exchanging "get" with "put" and "post" and trying to add "data" and "body" to the JSONObject, but no success. The received request body remains empty at the server.

Making a [post request with data in Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/sails.io.js/socket.post.html) was easy, and this is exactly what I want to do with the Java client. Is that possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use Android's HttpURLConnection (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)? It supports all the usual HTTP methods including POST and PUT.

Comment: The reason is that I want to make the request go through the socket, which I don't think is possible with HttpURLConnection, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: GET, POST, and PUT requests are part of the HTTP protocol. Sails seems to be attempting to simulate this on top of Socket.IO for some reason (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/blob/master/sails.io.js#L13-L15). Seems very strange to me!

Comment: @gregnr Yes, when you put it like that it sounds kind of strange to send HTTP requests over Socket.IO (or WebSockets). Although, the get request I wrote in my initial post is used to subscribe the requesting socket to events. I don't know how that can be done without sending the HTTP request via the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

1. You'll need to pass another JSONObject as a data

   ```
   JSONObject jsonObjectBody = new JSONObject();
   try {
       jsonObjectBody.put("sender", senderId);
       jsonObjectBody.put("recipient", recipientId);
       jsonObjectBody.put("message", message);
       jsonObjectBody.put("shop", shopId);
   } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }


   JSONObject jsonObjectRequest = new JSONObject();
   try {
       jsonObjectRequest.put("url", "/v1/chat/client/messages");
       jsonObjectRequest.put("data", jsonObjectBody);
   } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   socketInstance.emit("post", jsonObjectRequest, new Ack() {
       @Override
       public void call(Object... args) {
           Log.e("SocketUtil", "User sent a message");
       }
   });
   ```
2. Then on the server side you can get the body thus:

   ```
   const body = req.body;
   ```